# How to move all files in several subdirectories into one directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

Hello lets say we have a directory tree like this:

```
src/
src/sub1/a.cpp
src/sub2/b.cpp

lib/
lib/doc1.cpp
lib/doc2.cpp
```

how to move all those files into a common directory e.g. test such that the result in test directory will be like this:

```
test/
test/a.cpp
test/b.cpp
test/doc1.cpp
test/doc2.cpp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is Google broken? ;)

I found this with "move files into single directory linux"

http://www.howtogeek.com/wiki/Move_Files_Into_One_Directory_in_Linux_With_Find

Comment: i really searched, i swear :).